# C#: "One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found"

Tags: c#, ssis

I copy a code to delete the headers from a Excel file.
I got a error in the follow line:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet clsWorksheet =
                 (Excel.Worksheet)clsWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
```

The error is:

```
One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?
```

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkHzM.jpg)

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`Are you missing a reference?` You need to add an Excel Libary (.dll) to your project. If you have Excel installed, you should be able to find a "Microsoft Excel 11.0 Object Library"

Comment: I haven't Office installed in my computer. I can't use that library then?
I can see the library here: https://ibb.co/Bw4ZCQw isn't enought?